# JavaScript Locale Number Manipulation

Tags: javascript, numbers, locale

On my site I have a table with numerous numbers, and I'm doing simple math on them to find the best method for the user. The table looks something like this:

**`US` locale**

```
+-------+-------+------------+---------+----------------------------------------+
| Gain  | Price | Price/Gain | Amount  | Outcome (round(Price * Amount)) |
+-------+-------+------------+---------+----------------------------------------+
| 15.75 | 47    | 2.98       | 827,583 | 38,896,401                             |
| 52.5  | 240   | 4.57       | 248,275 | 59,586,000                             |
| 297.5 | 4,106 | 13.80      | 43,814  | 179,900,284                            |
+-------+-------+------------+---------+----------------------------------------+
```

**Here's how the table SHOULD look with the `de-DE` locale (notice the switching of the . and , characters)**

```
+-------+-------+------------+---------+----------------------------------------+
| Gain  | Price | Price/Gain | Amount  | Outcome (round(Price * Amount)) |
+-------+-------+------------+---------+----------------------------------------+
| 15,75 | 47    | 2,98       | 827.583 | 38.896.401                             |
| 52,5  | 240   | 4,57       | 248.275 | 59.586.000                             |
| 297,5 | 4.106 | 13,80      | 43.814  | 179.900.284                            |
+-------+-------+------------+---------+----------------------------------------+
```

The way my code works, each column is populated separately. So first, the `Gain` column is populated for **all** rows, formatted, and using `jQuery`, I changed the value of `row n` to the `Gain`. Then `Price` is calculated, and again the values are populated.

The issue arises when `Price/Gain` is calculated. For the `US` locale, everything is fine. But with the `de-DE` locale, the table *actually* ends up looking like this:

```
+-------+-------+------------+---------+----------------------------------------+
| Gain  | Price | Price/Gain | Amount  | Outcome (round(Price * Amount)) |
+-------+-------+------------+---------+----------------------------------------+
| 15,75 | 47    | 0,03       | 827.583 | 38.896.401                             |
| 52,5  | 240   | 0,46       | 248.275 | 59.586.000                             |
| 297,5 | 4.106 | 0,00       | 43.814  | 179.900                                |
+-------+-------+------------+---------+----------------------------------------+
```

When the `Price/Gain` is being calculated, the `,` and `.` are being ignored from the `Gain` and `Price` columns. As you can see in the third row,

```
4.106 / 2975 = 0.0014 (rounded to 0.00, or 0,00)
```

This is also causing an issue with the `Outcome`, as the `Price`, again, is being parsed literally, rather than converted from `de-DE` to US first. So in the third row, again, we can see

```
4.106 * 43814 (this is parsed correctly for some reason) = 179,900 or 179.900
```

Here's how my code is publishing these values and reading them in when needed:

```
// This code populates the Gain field
var gain = grabPresetGain(); // grabs a hardcoded value from a JSON object
gain = addCommasToNumber(new Intl.NumberFormat("de-DE", {}).format(gain .toFixed(2)));
row += "<div class='col-lg-1 col-md-1 col-sm-1 col-xs-1 row-gain text-center'>" + gain + "</div>";


// This code populates the price field
outcome = addCommasToNumber(new Intl.NumberFormat("de-DE", {}).format(outcome));
$(this).children(".row-price").text(outcome); 


// And finally this code populates the Price/Gain field

// for loop going through each row of the table

var gain = convertToNumber($(this).children(".row-gain").text());
var price = convertToNumber($(this).children(".row-price").text());

var pricePerGain = (price / gain);

pricePerGain = addCommasToNumber(new Intl.NumberFormat("de-DE", {minimumFractionDigits: 2, maximumFractionDigits: 2 }).format(pricePerGain .toFixed(2)));
$(this).children(".row-pricegain").text(pricePerGain );
```

And here's two of the helper functions being used:

```
function convertToNumber(x) {
    if (typeof x == "string") {
        x = x.replace(/\,/g,'');
    }
    return Number(x);
}

function addCommasToNumber(n) {
    return n.toLocaleString();
}
```

All in all - **is there a consistent way to parse, manipulate, and output numbers of different locales?**

Any insight would be great as I'm pretty stuck as to what to do at the moment.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Give [formatJS](https://formatjs.io/) a try. From the site:

> FormatJS is a modular collection of JavaScript libraries for internationalization that are focused on formatting numbers, dates, and strings for displaying to people.

If you're just dealing with numbers, you might even be able to get away without using a library at all, and just directly accessing the `window.Intl` object.

See some examples [here, on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/NumberFormat).

Comment: I can't tell if this will work if I'm not using one of their listed major frameworks

Comment: According to [their spec](https://formatjs.io/guides/runtime-environments/#intl-built-ins), the functionality is built around the `window.Intl` object  - which you can find documentation on from the [MDN Web Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Intl#Browser_Compatibility). `Intl` appears be universally supported according to [Can I Use](https://caniuse.com/#search=Intl)

Comment: I've updated my answer with an additional link to how to use the `Intl` object directly - which might be a better option for you if you're only working with numbers